# Zappa deployment successful without url

Tags: django, deployment, serverless, live, zappa

I am trying to deploy a django application through zappa. When I deploy the application everything works correctly and I also get the message "Your updated Zappa deployment is live". But I can't seem to find the url to access the live application. [image]

Answer (score 5):

You can access the url by typing `zappa status <stage>`, where `<stage>` is probably something like `dev`. See also https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa#status for details.

The printout will have your url as well as other status details of your lambda function.

This works provided you give full permission access to the IAM user (for testing purpose only) though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure my zappa_settigs.json by adding these lines:

```
"apigateway_enabled": true,
"manage_roles": true,
"cors": true,

**so the final zappa settings:**

{
"dev": {
    "django_settings": "zappatest.settings",
    "apigateway_enabled": true,
    "manage_roles": true,
    "role_arn": "Role_name",
    "role_arn": "arn_name",
    "profile_name": "default",
    "project_name": "project_name",
    "runtime": "python3.8",
    "s3_bucket": "bucket_name",
    "aws_region": "region_name",
    "cors": true,
    }
}
```